# Searching in Visual Studio 2010 Solution Explorer is difficult when

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any addin or feature available to locate a project, or a file in solution explorer directly without using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (find) ?
We are having 1000's of project , each having N number of files inside. 
Difficult to navigate using Find option.

Comment: 1000's of projects in 1 solution? If so, time to refactor your solution file.

Comment: Since it is a shared project already re factored .. People keep on updating it. Please provide a way to search  in soln explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution Navigator** from [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) adds a new tool window with soultion search.